# How would you name this c++ design pattern

Tags: c++, design-patterns

Knowing that this might be an inappropriate question (since the reply can be (will be) based only on personal, subjective opinions) I still risk asking it:

We wrote some code and came up with the following construct

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Generic
{
public: virtual void do_work() = 0;
};

class SomeAppDescriptor : public Generic
{
public: static std::string name() { return "SomeAppDescriptor"; }
};

template <class TGenericApp> 
class CommonFunctionalities : public TGenericApp
{
public: void do_common_work() {
            std::cout << "do_common_work for " << TGenericApp::name();
        }
};

class RealClass : public CommonFunctionalities<SomeAppDescriptor>
{
public: virtual void do_work() {
            do_common_work();
            std::cout << "and doing the work" << std::endl;
        }
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    RealClass a;
    a.do_work();
    return 0;
}
```

And now we are in the documentation phase ... We need to come up with a name for the construct where `CommonFunctionalities` inherits from the template member ... and is using the properties of the `SomeAppDescriptor` which is actually the template member... If you are to name this construct, what would be an appropriate name for it?

**Edit**

The main idea is that there are a lot of `AppDescriptor` classes which read some data from configuration files (name, ip, database, etc ...), and there is a middle layer (here it is represented by `CommonFunctionalities` which does the work (but also at some obscure point the `CommonFunctionalities` objects are mapped to `name()` (map of string and Generic) in order to get the functionality of the `do_work()`), and at the end someone from somewhere is calling the `do_work` of a `Generic` which is implemented in a set of "upper" layer classes (`RealClass`)

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this pattern? I cannot quite follow the basic idea behind it.

Comment: I'd say that's a mixin - isn't it? See Dr Dobbs: http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/mixin-based-programming-in-c/184404445

Comment: `CommonFunctionalities` use [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)

Comment: Seems to me this is called a "shim"? http://www.drdobbs.com/shim-classes/184401200?pgno=2

Comment: Mixin would fit quite well, yes; Also it may be possible to let `CommonFunctionalities` inherit from `Generic`, which should make the Mixin even more clear. But this depends on the context of the application (and what is needed within `AppDescriptor`)

Comment: @MatthiasB: I would not say this is a straight mix-in, since it inherits *both* non-virtual behavior AND virtual interface. Personally, I would call this *a mess*.

Comment: @MatthieuM. That's why I would Generic be the Base class of CommonFunctionalities, which clears things up a bit.

Comment: @MatthiasB: It's not even necessary here, you could have `RealClass` inherit from `Generic` and have `CommonFunc...` as an attribute.

Answer (score 2):

This looks, to me, like a botched attempt at a [Decorator](http://www.vincehuston.org/dp/decorator.html).

- `SomeAppDescriptor` and `CommonFunctionalities` do not override `do_work`, so they need not inherit from `Generic`; however the use of `do_common_work` suggests that might have been useful.
- if `RealClass` inherits from `Generic` directly, then it can take `CommonFunctionalities` by composition.

Using the Decorator pattern, I would end up with:

```
class Generic { public: virtual void do_work() = 0; };

template <typename App>
class CommonFunctionalities: public Generic {
public:
    virtual void do_work() override {
        std::cout << "CommonFunctionalities - " << App::name() << "\n";
    }
};

class RealClass: public Generic {
public:
    RealClass(std::unique_ptr<Generic> p): previous(std::move(p)) {}

    virtual void do_work() override {
        if (previous) { previous->do_work(); }
        std::cout << "RealClass\n";
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<Generic> previous;
};

int main() {
    RealClass rc{std::make_unique< CommonFunctionalities<SomeAppDescriptor> >()};

    Generic& g = rc;
    g.do_work();

    return 0;
}
```

The Decorator was *specifically* created to layer the work, without any class knowing more than the interface class so that you can *at runtime* choose which layers to use. Even if the runtime flexibility is not necessary, it can still be advantageous to use this approach because it reduces the dependencies: `RealClass` knows not of `CommonFunctionalities`.

*Note: in C++, you can also use the `Decorator` approach without interfaces thanks to templates.*

Answer (score 0):

It's the [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

Comment: It *uses* CRTP, but is more complex than straight CRTP; this is a common thing with design patters, often times an application design uses *several* of them.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's somewhat of an upgrade to the [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

looks nice. :)